# ios::nocreate error while compiling a C++ code

Tags: c++, linux, g++, iostream

While, compiling a package, written in C++ on RHEL 5.0. I am getting the following error.

**> error: `nocreate` is not a member of `std::ios`**

The source-code corresponds to:

> ifstream tempStr(`argv[4]`,`ios::in`|`ios::nocreate`);

---

I have tried

> #g++ -O -Wno-deprecated <file.cpp> -o <file>

as well as:

> #g++ -O  -o <file>

**Please suggest a solution.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ios::nocreate` is not part of standard C++ - what are you expecting it to do?

Edit: From a Google, it seems like it was intended to prevent the file being created if it doesn't already exist. This is the default for ifstreams anyway, so you can just say:

```
ifstream f( filename );
if ( ! f.is_open() ) {
    // open failed - probably because infput file does not exist  
}
```

Comment: I am building an open source package, and this error is being thrown up. Not much ssupport is available by them Hence wanted to know.

Comment: "ios::nocreate is not part of standard C++ - what are you expecting it to do?" - seriously?

Comment: This is problematic, since it introduces a racecondition: Another process could create the file between the two open statements.

Answer (score 7):

Opening a file in read mode (`ios::in`) won't create it if it doesn't exist. You can just leave off the non-standard `nocreate`. And since `in` is the default for `ifstream`:

```
ifstream tempStr (argv[4]);
```

Comment: This is problematic, since it introduces a racecondition: Another process could create the file between the two open statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file as a filehandle using fopen and O_CREAT|O_EXCL and then convert it to a stream using

```
__gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf<char> filebuf(posix_handle, std::ios::out);
    ostream os(&filebuf);
```

this uses a non standard extension defined in .
If anyone has a better solution, i really want to know!