# Using ios::Nocreate flag results in "undeclared identifier" error

Tags: c++, fstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ios::nocreate error while compiling a C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062861/iosnocreate-error-while-compiling-a-c-code)

i have been working on how to create a simple lexical compiler in c++/c# but it seems i have a an error when i try to compile the program the error is

```
error c2065 'nocreate' undeclared identifier
```

how can i handle this problem??but im thinking maybe it has to do with the fstream header,any ideas on how i can handle it??

this is the code where it is giving me an error

```
loadTransitionTable( );

    fstream File("input.txt", ios::in|ios::Nocreate);

    if (!File)
    {
       cout<<"\n Unable to open the input file."<<endl;
       cout<<"\n Press any key to exit.";

       getch( );
       exit(0);
```

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062861/iosnocreate-error-while-compiling-a-c-code

Comment: Maybe because there is no `nocreate` flag? If you open with `ios::in` (which if the default for `ifstream`) no file will be created if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are with VisualStudio, try

```
std::fstream File("input.txt", std::ios::in|std::ios::_Nocreate);
```

Answer (score 12):

`ios::Nocreate` is not part of standard C++, but if the intention is to prevent the file being created if it doesn't already exist, you can relax. This is the default for ifstreams anyway, so you can just say:

```
fstream File("input.txt", ios::in);
```

Answer (score 3):

The standard c++ library doesn't define `std::ios::Nocreate`. Files opened for reading aren't created anyway, so you can leave it out:

> fstream File("input.txt", ios::in);

or just use:

> ifstream File("input.txt");